# I am getting this error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, jupyter

I have written this code:

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer()
text_tf = tf.fit_transform(df_clean)
text_tf

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_tf,test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
```

and I am getting this error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`.
I tried many ways to remove this error but all was in vain. Can you explain to me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `train_test_split` function from `sklearn` splits arrays/datasets into two, meaning that for every array passed in you will get two arrays back (one with the training data and one with the test data). In most examples two arrays are passed in, with one being the array with features (`X`) and the second one being the values you are trying to predict (`y`). In your example you are only passing in one array to the `train_test_split` function, which is then split into two and giving you two arrays back instead of four. Your code however expects four since you are trying to unpack the data into four different variables (`x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train`, and `y_test`). The correct way to solve this error would therefore be to only unpack the data into two variables, for example `train, test = train_test_split(text_tf,test_size=0.1, random_state=1)`.